# ruby basic method exercise for codewars, indexing

Tags: ruby

I am working on the following codewars exercise. I am pretty new still to Ruby and have been stuck on making the last method work. Currently each method works fine with the test code, except for the 'def page_index'. Am I missing something here? I can't seem to nail down what I am doing wrong with this section. Any help/guidance is appreciated! I'd also like to point out that I deleted all of the other test code, and just have the portion for the method that doesn't work currently.

The code was given to us as a part of the exercise, and we were told to fix the code to make it run with the test code provided at the bottom. For the method I am having trouble with, the instructions were: page_index takes an item index and returns the page that it belongs on, it determines what page an item is on, has zero based indexes, this method should return -1 for item_index values that are out of range.

```
    class PaginationHelper

    attr_accessor :collection, :items_per_page

    def initialize(collection, items_per_page)
        @collection = collection
        @items_per_page = items_per_page
    end

    def item_count
        puts @collection.length
    end

    def page_count
        puts @collection.length - items_per_page
    end


    def page_item_count(page_index)
        page_item_count = @items_per_page - page_index
        if page_index >= 2
            puts -1, "Page is invalid."
        else 
            puts (@items_per_page - page_index)
        end
    end

    def page_index(index)
        index = @collection - item_index.to_i
        if page_index >= 2
            puts -1, "Page is out of range"
        else 
            puts (@collection-index.to_i)
        end
    end
end


helper = PaginationHelper.new(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 4)


helper.page_index(5) 
helper.page_index(2) 
helper.page_index(20) 
helper.page_index(-10)
```

Comment: The last version of this question had better formatting.

Comment: According to your page_cont method. If i have 41 items and 10 per page, `page_count` will be 31, right? I guess it should be 5, so first fix that.

Comment: Where does `item_index` come from in the `initialize` method?
There is not passed in the calling of `new`.

Comment: Mark - item_index is not supposed to be in the initialize method. I had added it in there, but mistake.

Comment: zishe - can you please elaborate? because I am not following how I would fix that to be 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the following code is what you are looking for:

```
class PaginationHelper
  attr_accessor :collection, :items_per_page

  def initialize(collection, items_per_page)
    @collection = collection
    @items_per_page = items_per_page
  end

  def item_count
    puts @collection.length
  end

  def page_count
    puts @collection.length - items_per_page
  end

  def page_item_count(page_index)
    page_item_count = @items_per_page - page_index
    if page_index >= 2
      puts -1, "Page is invalid."
    else 
      puts (@items_per_page - page_index)
    end
  end

  def page_index(item_index)
    index = @collection.length - item_index
    if index <= 0 || item_index < 0
      puts "-1\tPage is out of range"
    else 
      puts (item_index / items_per_page).to_i
    end
  end
end

helper = PaginationHelper.new(['a','b','c','d','e','f'], 4)

helper.page_index(5) 
helper.page_index(2) 
helper.page_index(20) 
helper.page_index(-10)
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps clarify some things.